# Stored procedures are getting vanished in mysql after relogin to phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, vps

I have created MySQL database using cpanel and created required tables, stored procedures in it from phpmyadmin.

After creating, at the end as usual I logged out from both cpanel and phpmyadmin too.

Next day I logged in to cPanel and then opened phpmyadmin, what I found is list of all the stored procedures is there; but there definitions is not there. And even "Edit" & "Execute" options were also disabled.

I am using VPS from well known hosting company.

I have never faced this type of problem from any other hosting company.

I also given proper privileges to database user. But still not able sort out this problem.

Is it something my fault or is it some sort of setting which we have to set from WHM panel or cPanel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do/did you have rights to create stored procedures, is this the first time you are exercising the right ? What was the response of the hosting company ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Whirl Mind. This is not the first time I am doing this thing. I have created databases with stored procedures, views, triggers and with many other features for many number of times. Hosting company says that they are not responsible for this. But I have doubt whether there is some sort of setting in MySQL configuration somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

After some R&D, I found that whatever users are being created through cPanel, they don't have super privileges. And hence they can create stored procedures but once they log out they wont be able to edit them. This is what by default settings done by hosting company.